# Microsoft Word: copy paste doesn't work outside of application

Tags: ms-office, big-sur, copy-paste

I have:

- Microsoft Office 16.45 installed from Mac App Store.
- MacOS 11.1 Big Sur

I am trying:

- Copy anything from any application except Word itself
- Paste inside of Word application

The problem is it doesn't work, it seems that copy/paste buffer is locked inside of application. Is there anything I am missing or is it a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here (same software versions). Did you try a reboot?

Comment: It started working after couple of restarts of Word (without restart of computer). I will try to reproduce it again for a couple of weeks until I will close this question

Comment: I have always had this problem. If I have copied anything from Word earlier in the same session, and then copy something else from outside of Word, when I paste in Word, the earlier material from Word will be pasted, not the new material from outside Word. I also notice that dragging and dropping from another application into Word still works.

Comment: i have this issue in word 2021. no paste outside word . And it happens because i have installed the "Language Tool" app installed version 537.36  (win 11) https://languagetool.org. If i copy&paste into Language tool it works and then i can copy again into anywhere i want.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this problem when trying to copy from Word to AutoCAD (and even started to have problems copying and pasting from Word to Microsoft Onenote or even Notepad... it just wasn't pasting). The issue is the paragraph settings. The only way to get around this if you're having trouble is to copy the text from the word doc... make a new word doc... paste it, select all and then change the "style" to "Normal." This gets rid of all the formatting, paragraph and numbering stuff. So it sucks cuz you lose all the numbering and whatnot, but if you had the issue I had then it's the only way I found to fix it. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a site for users of Apple hardware and macOS based software. Are you sure your answer is relevant here?